# Why can't I put a class literally above the partial class of my Form1?

Tags: c#, class

Googling for a answer to this question I just learned that classes belong into extra files.
But anyway I would like to know why you cannot put a class like this:

```
class Tables
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
...
```

If I put it to the bottom it works?? why? I thought classes are separated?

```
"System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler"
```

Comment: judging by the code you've provided -- your class closes with an open brace instead of a closed one... could be an issue ;)

Comment: It is a simple restriction in the Winforms designer, it reads back your code and does not want to make too many guesses where it might be located.  Because then it might guess wrong.  The error message is *very* explicit: "The class Form1 can be designed, but it is not the first class in the file".  So make it the first one, simple.

Comment: A class which is bring used in Visual Studio Designer must be the first class in the .cs file. That is why you cannot put your tables class at the beginning. If you are not working with a windows forms designed class then you can put the classes in whatever order you want.

Comment: Ok sorry that typo was just a typo...it doesn't work without the typo too. I thought so that it has something to do with that splitted generated design,...just as I thought I start to understand classes, was this unlogical why its now working. thx Hans and CathalMF

Comment: You can put it to the end; should be good enough. And classes worthy of re-use deserve to be placed in cs files of their own anyway..!

Comment: thx for the downvote I cannot ask anymore questions.blocked...I thought its a legitimate question...since asking google is quiet difficult, regarding to formulate the question...haha thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinForms designer can design only the first class in the file.

Comment: That is indeed explaining a lot of my struggles I had....will keep it separated from now on anyway :)